# Disable Collision for 3 seconds

Tags: objective-c, collision

I am trying to disable collisions by setting the physicsBody to nil for 3 seconds on my player object. I have tried the following but it simply doesnt work. Thanks for any advice.

```
double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)
(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
NSLog(@"Do some work");
self.player.physicsBody = nil;
});
```

Comment: You want to pause it for 3 seconds.  So what is "double delayInSeconds = 10.0;" for?

Comment: Hi, Yes dont mind that. I change it to 3 and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer simply by disabling collision oas soon as didBeginContact is triggered, then used timer to set the collision back after 3 seconds. Just had to rethink my logic but it was easier than I thought. Working code as Follow:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{

NSLog(@"contact detected");
//Disbale Collision
self.player.physicsBody = nil;
//time i want to delay
double delayInSeconds = 3.0;
//Delay func
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)
(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
NSLog(@"Log Delay");
//enable collision after 3 seconds
self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.frame.size];
});
```

Thats it.